# Find and replace text in a file between range of lines using sed

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed

I have a big text file (URL.txt) and I wish to perform the following using a single *sed* command:

1. Find and replace text 'google' with 'facebook' between line numbers 19 and 33.
2. Display the output on the terminal without altering the original file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I would like to be on the record downvoting @jww's comment. It is a perfectly useful and valid question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use sed addresses:

```
sed '19,33s/google/facebook/g' file
```

This will run the substitution on lines between and including 19 and 33.

The form of a sed command is as follows:

```
[address[,address]]function[arguments]
```

Where `19,33` is the addreses,
`s`ubstitute is function
and `g`lobal is the argument

Comment: does line numbering start at 0 or 1?

Comment: They start at `1` and the last line can be addressed with `$`, Try it for yourself: `seq 5 | sed '1d;$d'`

Answer (score 4):

the above answer ALMOST worked for me on Mac OSX.

> sed '19,33s/google/facebook/' file

worked perfectly without braces.

> sed '19,$s/google/facebook/' file

works until the end of the file as well.

Comment: Consider linking the answer you're referring to instead of referencing "the above answer", as the answer may not be on top of yours for ever :)

Comment: Using this option on linux also works, and 19 and 33 were both inclusive.