# Explanation of complicated sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed

What is this doing? What are these: `!b`, `:a`, `:trail`?

```
sed -i -e '/LIMOC_SECTION=SERVICENAME_FULSC/!b' -e ':a' \
    -e "s/^PRIMARY_IP=.*/PRIMARY_IP=${primaryip}/;t trail" \
    -e 'n;ba' -e ':trail' -e 'n;btrail' $ssocfg
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten:

```
# If a line does not match "LIMOC_SECTION=SERVICENAME_FULSC", jump to end
# (leave untouched)
/LIMOC_SECTION=SERVICENAME_FULSC/! b

# Label "a"
:a

# Substitute everything on the right side of "=" with the contents of $primaryip
s/^PRIMARY_IP=.*/PRIMARY_IP=${primaryip}/

# If there was a substitution on the current line, jump to label "trail"
t trail

# Print pattern space and read next line
n

# Jump to label "a"
b a

# Label "trail"
:trail

# Print pattern space and read next line
n

# Jump to label "trail"
b trail
```

What this effectively does is substituting `$primaryip` on the right-hand side of the line starting with `PRIMARY_IP=`, but only for the first occurrence after the line matching `LIMOC_SECTION=SERVICENAME_FULSC`.

It's a combination of [how to replace only the first occurrence in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file) with [replacing only within a limited range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149036/find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-between-range-of-lines-using-sed).

As for the individual commands and options used:

- The [`-i` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002di) is for in-place editing.
- The [`-e` options](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002de) mark individual parts of the sed script.
- [`:label`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_003a-_0028label_0029-command) is a mark in a sed program that can be jumped to using the `b` or `t` branching commands.
- [`b`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-b-_0028branch_0029-command) is unconditional branching. If used without a label, it branches to the end of all commands, i.e., just prints the pattern space. If used with a label, it jumps to that label.
- [`t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-t-_0028test-and-branch-if-successful_0029-command) is conditional branching: the branching only happens if there was a successful substitution since the last line was read or since the last branching command.
- [`n`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-n-_0028next_002dline_0029-command) reads the next line into pattern space and prints the current one (unless auto-printing is suppressed; not the case here).
- [`s`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) is the substitution command.

I'd say the command could be simplified, though:

```
sed -i '/LIMOC_SECTION=SERVICENAME_FULSC/,$ {
    1,/^PRIMARY_IP=.*/ s/^\(PRIMARY_IP=\).*/\1'"$primaryip"'/
}' "$ssocfg"
```

does the same. It takes the range of lines from the one matching `LIMOC_SECTION` to the end of the file, and within that range, it performs the substitution on the first line that matches `PRIMARY_IP`.