# How to comment out particular lines in a shell script at a time

Tags: notepad++

Can anyone suggest how to comment particular lines in the shell script?

Suppose I have a script of 500 lines and
I want to comment 150 lines (from "300 to 450"), How to comment it at a time?

Comment: Uh, use a text editor?

Comment: I'd probably use `sed` (not really, awk), here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149036/find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-between-range-of-lines-using-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `vi` as your text editor you could use

```
:300,450s/^/#&/
```

This will prepend `#` to all lines from 300 to 450.

Or you could go to the first line you want to comment, mark it with label `a` using

```
:ma
```

then go to the last line and enter

```
:a,.s/^/#&/
```

This will do the same substitution from the line marked with `a` to the current line

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I got the solution

In Notepad++, select the lines you want to comment out.
Press ctrl+K , it will put # before the line.

Comment: Yeah, its a shell script, I am using Notepad++ as a TextEditor.

Comment: Thanks @James Brown Your answer is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Many text editors provide feature of recording macros. I specifically find this fearure easy in Notepad++.

Here is a good tutorial if you want to understand more about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--wY1sWFVwI

So for you to avoid reworking:

Rocord a macro that

1.) goes to begin of the line

2.) adds a #

3.) changes the cursor to new line

and then you can run it for 150 times in one click,when you are at line number 300.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -ne 'if(($.>300)&&($.<450)){print "#$_"} else {print}' yourfilename`

This  iterates over the lines and if the line number is in the range you specify, prepends a #.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^/#/ if 300 .. 449'`